# How to use Biblio Inline references in D7?

Tags: 7

I'm working on an online handbook with Drupal 7. For managing the high number of bibliography references I am using the Bibliography Module. In the documentation I found the following explanation for adding biblio citations inline:

> Adding Biblio Citations Inline
>
> First, the Biblio module references filter has to be enabled. This is under:
>
> Home » Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats
>
> Then you can use the syntax described there to add references to biblio resources within the text of other content:

```
<cite><bib> or [bib]
Use <bib>citekey</bib> or [bib]citebkey[/bib] to insert automatically numbered references. </cite>
```

> The cite key is available under Identifiers in the bibliographic reference.

https://groups.drupal.org/node/2829

I can't find the path to the Text formats settings and the Identifiers option. So how can I add inline references to Biblio content at the end of my handbook pages?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.